# AWS EC2 instance -> Microsoft Windows Server -> Run Power BI Smoothly + Cost Effective

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to get the Microsoft Windows Server on hourly basis (On-Demand configuration) from AWS EC2. I don't know which configuration is good as there is various options like t1, t2, t3.

My requirement:

I want Online Windows OS where I can install the Microsoft Power BI Software and create reports and a dashboard.

I go through the configuration options but don't know which one can provide cost effective consistent window os performance.

Please let me know which Windows OS Server hourly configuration I can have that don't hang or slow down while working.

Comment: What is the size of your data models? What is your definition for "smoothly"?

Comment: is this just for Power BI Desktop? You can only create reports not the 'dashboard' experience you get in the service

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Power Bi recommends[2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install) a minimum configuration of

1. An 8-core CPU
2. 8 GB of memory
3. A 64-bit version of Windows Server 2012 R2 or later
4. Solid-state drive (SSD) storage for spooling.

Based on that, on the AWS server you could use
a.

- AMI Name: Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base-2021.10.13
- Instance Type [1](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/?trkCampaign=acq_paid_search_brand&sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_GB&sc_publisher=Google&sc_category=Cloud%20Computing&sc_country=GB&sc_geo=EMEA&sc_outcome=acq&sc_detail=aws%20ec2%20cloud&sc_content=%7Bad%20group%7D&sc_matchtype=e&sc_segment=489216384637&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CBrand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CCloud%20Computing%7CEC2%7CGB%7CEN%7CSitelink&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!489216384637!e!!g!!aws%20ec2%20cloud&ef_id=Cj0KCQjw_fiLBhDOARIsAF4khR2_iIaiMR_1Qj2k6QwyHBrZcXmTmm2MOg_v8xa-DYeQIOVCfBbKxIEaAgYwEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!489216384637!e!!g!!aws%20ec2%20cloud) : t2.large should be sufficient however it totally depends on the frequency of data refreshes which are scheduled and the amount of data processing that is needed.  Best to start off with t2.2xlarge is what if it is affordable.

Reference Urls:

[Gateway Installation Recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-install)

[AWS Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/?trkCampaign=acq_paid_search_brand&sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_GB&sc_publisher=Google&sc_category=Cloud%20Computing&sc_country=GB&sc_geo=EMEA&sc_outcome=acq&sc_detail=aws%20ec2%20cloud&sc_content=%7Bad%20group%7D&sc_matchtype=e&sc_segment=489216384637&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CBrand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CCloud%20Computing%7CEC2%7CGB%7CEN%7CSitelink&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!489216384637!e!!g!!aws%20ec2%20cloud&ef_id=Cj0KCQjw_fiLBhDOARIsAF4khR2_iIaiMR_1Qj2k6QwyHBrZcXmTmm2MOg_v8xa-DYeQIOVCfBbKxIEaAgYwEALw_wcB:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!489216384637!e!!g!!aws%20ec2%20cloud)

More detailed steps to install and connect to the AWS database on the power bi web app are commented here:

[Refresh AWS RDS database from Power BI Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974573/refresh-aws-rds-database-from-power-bi-web/69787447#69787447)