# Connection failure Postgresql on AWS-RDS Instance in a private network from PowerBI Desktop & Service

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS (PostgreSQL) that is inside a private network - only accessible via a VPN and Bastian Host.

I am able to establish connection  from PBI Desktop to  "PostgreSQL-RDS Instance." By creating SSH tunneling from my Laptop (localhost) to Bastian Host using   ODBC Driver. With this approach all the data is imported onto PBI desktop(import mode).
But our requirement is to establish connection through a direct query to refresh data real time and generate the Reports Dynamically which I am not able to.
I entered the database credentials into the Power BI desktop tool, and it not working correctly in the power bi desktop, getting a Timeout Error.
I must use direct query, I can't use import.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An exact error that you are getting would help get to the root cause of the issue.  However, a few basic troubleshooting steps that I'd suggest are:

1. Ensure that you have a compatible version of the software installed on your machine such as the Npgsql-4.0.9.  AT times the latest version of the software usually causes issues.
2. Ensure that you remove the semicolon at the end of the query.

Once you get the query running successfully on the desktop version, when you publish it to the web version, the visuals will not be able to connect to the database unless an on-premises data gateway is setup.  To do so, more details on setting up a data gateway to automatically refresh the dataset for the power bi web version are here:

[Refresh AWS RDS database from Power BI Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974573/refresh-aws-rds-database-from-power-bi-web/69787447#69787447Once) you are successfully able to query directly