# SQL Server (Hosted on AWS RDS) with Real Time Updates on Power BI

Tags: amazon-web-services, powerbi, amazon-rds

I have a MySQL database instance running on AWS RDS. I would like to build a dashboard with the data hosted on this database which updates with minimal latency on Power BI as otherwise  a scheduled refresh can only be done for 8 times a day.

Explored a few options on how to develop this and stumbled upon 'Real Time Streaming' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming) which can be done on Power BI. Within this, there are two options :

- Using the Power BI REST APIs
- Using the Streaming Dataset UI

If I'm using the API's to push to a dataset, the documentation states that I'd have to register on Azure which I do not want to unless its free. I would like to know if there are any alternative routes that I can proceed with or if this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

What you would have to do is connect to an on-Premises Data Gateway.  This needs to be installed on the AWS environment.  Detailed steps are mentioned here.
[Refresh AWS RDS database from Power BI Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974573/refresh-aws-rds-database-from-power-bi-web/69787447#69787447)

However the scheduled refresh default options available as of today are either weekly or daily. You will need to add additional time schedules within the day to refresh the data more frequently.  This means that the data on the visuals will not be refreshed in realtime but only once the dataset is refreshed based on the schedules you have set.